# How can I solve this problem without doing it by hand?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, problem-solving, computational-mathematics, open-problem

I'm dealing with the following problem in computational programming. I'm trying to find a way to build an algorithm that can quickly resolve the following problem statement without forcing me to do it by hand. Is there any way to group the following relations below by some pattern or identity in order to make finding a possible values of c much more efficiently?

> Problem: Given any integer x, where x > 2, is there any integer c,
> where c >= 1 that satisfies the following relations for some integer k,
> where k >= 0.

1. $\frac{x}{11 + 10k} = c \Rightarrow x = 11c + 10ck$
2. $\frac{x}{3  + 10k} = c \Rightarrow x = 3c  + 10ck$
3. $\frac{x}{7  + 10k} = c \Rightarrow x = 7c  + 10ck$
4. $\frac{x}{9  + 10k} = c \Rightarrow x = 9c  + 10ck$

## Example $\#1$: $x = 3$

*From $\#2$*: $3 = 3c + 10ck$, so $k = 0, c = 1$ satisfy this relation.

## Example $\#2$: $x = 4$

*From $\#1$*: $c = \frac{4}{11 + 10k}$, so for any $k \ge 0$, the denominator will always be larger than $4$. No integer value of $c \ge 1$ will ever satisfy this equation.

*From $\#2$*: $c = \frac{4}{3  + 10k}$, so for $k = 0$, the denominator does not divide evenly into $4$. For $k \ge 1$, the denominator will always be larger than $4$. No integer value of $c \ge 1$ will ever satisfy this equation.

*From $\#3$*: $c =\frac{4}{7  + 10k}$, so for any $k \ge 0$, the denominator will always be larger than $4$. No integer value of $c \ge 1$ will ever satisfy this equation.

*From $\#4$*: $c = \frac4{9  + 10k}$, so for any $k \ge 0$, the denominator will always be larger than $4$. No integer value of $c \ge 1$ will ever satisfy this equation.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate since it is for c >= 1. The other question is for c > 1. That makes a huge difference. I realized after Barry wrote his answer that I made that mistake but, I wanted to keep the question around because why take down a problem with a great answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relations pick out the numbers $x$ that have an odd prime divisor not equal to $5$.  Hence the only numbers not covered are those of the form $x=2^m\cdot5^n$.

Comment: Barry, are you sure? Because for x = 8, it does not satisfy any of the above relations, yet it also is not of the form x = (2^m)(5^n).

Comment: @Alexandru, $8=2^3\cdot5^0$.

Comment: My mistake...let me think this over a little bit more...so if what you're saying is true, then I think it follows that all prime numbers must meet these three conditions: (1) Not modulo divide evenly by 2, (2) Not modulo divide evenly by 5, (3) Must not be of the form (2^n)(5^m), is that correct?

Comment: You see, my 4 relations are all primality tests. If x % y = 0 it follows that x / y = c for some integer c >= 1 if y > 0. If you modulus out 2 from x, and then modulus out 5 from x, you eliminate the multiples of 2 and 5. The only tests left on x are for integers ending in 1, 3, 7, and 9 that are greater than 1. That's how I came up with the four relations.

Comment: I think I see the error in my problem statement now. Perhaps it should have restricted to be c > 1 instead of >= 1...because this works, but it only works since, for example 37...37 is divisible by itself, but for primality I am interested in denominators less than itself...

Comment: Barry, I think this is the final version of what I actually meant this time (I really hope): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840308/how-can-i-solve-this-problem-without-having-to-do-it-by-hand